# How to rotate a CALayer on touch?

Tags: iphone, calayer, uitouch

I am making a analog clock.It has a hand which can be used to set the alarm time.I am using CALayer for this purpose.It has clock hand image as its contents.

**1)How can i rotate or drag this hand on touch without animation in both clockwise and anticlockwise directions?**

**Edit:** I was able to drag the hand in clockwise direction using following code

```
 - (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
    {       
        touch=[[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint p=[touch locationInView:touch.view];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(clockView1.draghand.frame, p)) 
        {
            [CATransaction begin];
            CGFloat dragangle = Deg2Radians(1);
            [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0];
            clockView1.draghand.transform = CATransform3DRotate(clockView1.draghand.transform,dragangle, 0, 0, 1);
            [CATransaction commit]; 
        }
}
```

**Now,How can i rotate it in anti-clockwise direction?How can i detect whether user is dragging hand in clockwise or anti-clockwise direction?**

Comment: Hi, You got the Solution?